# Login MVC y Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente con querer loguearme desde MVC a SQL Server, el problema es porque mi campo contrasenha está encriptada. Esta es la estructura de mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [Administracion].[LoginUsuario](
    [IdLoginUsuario] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NombreUsuario] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Contrasenha] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [IdTipoUsuario] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Mi código para validar el usuario es:

```
ALTER procedure [Administracion].[ValidarUsuario]
    @NombreUsuario nvarchar(15),
    @Contrasenha nvarchar(max)
    as
    begin
      SELECT 1 
      FROM Administracion.LoginUsuario 
      WHERE NombreUsuario = @NombreUsuario and PWDCOMPARE(@Contrasenha,Contrasenha) = 1
    end;
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
public partial class LoginUsuario
{
    public int IdLoginUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NombreUsuario { get; set; }
    public byte[] Contrasenha { get; set; }
    //public string Contrasenha { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdTipoUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

Este es mi código donde consumo mi procedimiento:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginUsuario objUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (SIMaquinariayServiciosEntities db = new SIMaquinariayServiciosEntities() )
        {
            var obj = db.LoginUsuario.Where(a => a.NombreUsuario.Equals(objUser.NombreUsuario) && a.Contrasenha.Equals(objUser.Contrasenha)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (obj != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = obj.IdLoginUsuario.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = obj.NombreUsuario.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");
            }
        }
    }
    return View(objUser);
}
```

Me sale este error:

> Longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres Base-64.

Creo que debe ser por mi tipo de dato de mi base de datos. Cuando lo hago sin encriptación me funciona super bien pero debo encriptar el campo contraseña.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad contraseña de la class tiene que ser `string`, esta correcta la que tienes comentada

```
public string Contrasenha { get; set; }
```

Si analiza la documentacion

[PWDCOMPARE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdcompare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

observaras que el parametro que espera es un `nvarchar(128)`

Ademas defines esto mismo como parametro del procedure cuando usas:

```
@Contrasenha nvarchar(max)
```

Comment: Leandro Gracias

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: 'The type 'Edm.Binary' of the member 'Contrasenha' in the conceptual side type 'SIMaquinariayServiciosModel.LoginUsuario' does not match with the type 'System.String' of the member 'Contrasenha' on the object side type 'CapaPresentacion.Models.LoginUsuario'.'

Comment: En esta parte de mi codigo

Comment: porque menciona un mapping ? se supone que estas invocando un procedure, no es un mapping directo de la class LoginUsuario con la tabla

Comment: La verdad como debo hacerlo por favor, es que ya estoy estancado ahi y no puedo sali y necesito avanzar

Comment: no se como aconsejarte porque no entiendo porque defines un procedure pero depsues defines una query en linq cuando usas db.LoginUsuario.Where(), tienes que ejeutar el procedure no entity framework, o quizas mapear el procedure

Comment: desde el linq de entity framework no vas a eejcutar nunca el procedure que usa PWDCOMPARE()

Comment: Muy bien gracias intentare. muchas gracias

Comment: @RobertoCarlosMelgar Marca la respuesta como aceptada para mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas con respuestas aceptadas) Saludos